# How can I fix the error massage " "OplRun is not responding, you must relaunch the Run" in Cplex?

Tags: cplex

I have created a model with small data and this model works, but when I want to implement the model with big data, I get an error message.

Small Model: it has 2 warehouses, 5 schools(as distribution centers),4 regions Regions with their demanding population

Big Model:  It has 3 warehouses,631 Schools (distribution centers),138 Regions with their demanding population. The aim of the Model is to minimize the costs.

The first question is: if the model with small data works well, that means the model with big data will work too?

The second question is: How can I fix the error?

For fixing the error  I tried these ways:
First: I changed the Memory in the .ops file up to 5000 or 10000000 but I got the same Error after 1 hour.

2nd: I followed this link "[Ibm support link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwlBm.jpg) " and the Path **" The log file are .metadata.log and .metadata.oplrun.log "**
I came to the Note file, but I did not understand where the error is.

Could you help me? Thank you in Advance

[Error in Cplex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwlBm.jpg)
[The file Notepad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1mFK.png)

Answer (score 0):

You may face some out of memory issue.

Can you try to use oplrun outside the IDE ?
Can you try

```
execute
{
cplex.threads=1;
}
```

in the model ?

You may have a look at https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/avoiding-out-memory-errors-opl

Comment: you are right, it was a memory issue. Thank You.