# CPLEX oplrun terminates with unexpected error

Tags: runtime-error, cplex, opl

I have a MILP model which is written in OPL and solved by CPLEX 12.7.
When I run the solver from OPL IDE (Optimization Studio), an optimal solution is found.
However, invoking `oplrun Modfile.mod Datfile.dat` I get an unexpected error:

```
<<< setup

### UNEXPECTED ERROR ...
```

This happens when calling cplex.solve();

I do not know where to find log files for oplrun.exe.

In a previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67299330/how-can-i-fix-the-error-massage-oplrun-is-not-responding-you-must-relaunch-t) I read a hint to set

```
execute{
    cplex.threads = 1;
};
```

When I include this setting into the mod file the execution with oplrun terminates
without error but finds no solution. OPL IDE also terminates without error but also
finds no solution (solution status 4). Both runs seem identical.
However, as stated above, before including the cplex.threads snippet the IDE found an optimal solution.

What are possible reasons for the unexpected error when running oplrun.exe and why does
the IDE not show this error. I assume the IDE calls oplrun in the background. If it is a memory
issue, how do I configure it appropriately for oplrun? I also tried to invoke `oplrun -p . RunConfig` but
the unexpected error still occured.

Furthermore, from the console output of the IDE I found that if cplex.threads is not set explicitly the solution process runs with "up to 16 threads." When I set `cplex.threads = 16` and run
`oplrun Modfile.mod Datfile.dat` it still results in the unexpected error but
`oplrun -p . RunConfig` terminates successfully and provides the same solution as the IDE.

I appreciate your help.